# What computer should I buy?

Tags: virtual-machines

I’m an app developer and I’m developing using Xcode and android studio. And I have recently started developing with ionic and generally I like exploring many programming languages, frameworks etc.
This is basically a hobby but sometimes (for example, now) I’m doing projects for companies.
Also, I’ll probably need to install windows (parallels) to work with visual studio on a final project for my computer science class.

Right now, I have a Mac mini (16 gb ram and 1tb ssd). But I want something a bit more portable. I’m thinking of buying MacBook Pro 15”. 
I would love to get recommendations whether I should get an upgrade for 1tb storage/32gb ram or perhaps 512gb storage and 16gb ram is enough. Other ideas are welcomed, of course.

I’m asking that because if I don’t need those upgrades, (obviously) it’ll save money and I kinda need that (I’m collecting my money from previous jobs of developing and hope to get the rest of the amount from future jobs so I can return it to my parents) not a problem, but if possible than why not‍♂️
Thank you for answers

Comment: Wall of text. Can you format this a little better so it is more readable?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths hopefully it’s better

Comment: Hi, I think you can structure your question / write it a bit more clearly. Maybe split it into sections: **(a)** what's your current system, what do you do with it?  **(b)** what are the limits of your current system? want do you want to do with the new system? what do you expect of the new system? (*e.g. be more portable*) **(c)** what are you currently considering? **(d)** your actual question (*1TB+32GB vs. 500GB+16GB vs. other ideas*) — additional notes like in the last paragraph are often not necessary for answering the question — also, try to make the question's title more descriptive